# Should Unity 8 have extensions for customizability

Tags: community, unity

I belief that Unity needs somewhat of a customizability features.  What better time to put it in while they are rewriting the code in C++ for version 8.  I think it's more customizable than the applet features of many desktop environment like KDE, XFCE, to just name a few, because you can change/add the appearance, layout, functionality of something about it.  How could I, or anyone change the layout, and functionality of the KDE's logout dialog? If you try, nice luck with that, without forking the code.  For example, I miss the Dodge Window feature for the launcher when they remove it in version 5.2 of unity, the default version that comes with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, Their was a fork of unity that re-added that feature, the problem was the person/team who fork it needed to fork it.  I know there is this one extension for Gnome-Shell that allows you to auto-hide the top panel.  There is no truly way to theme unity to the fullest it could be done like the menus.  The best thing about extensions is that the Unity team don't need to maintain them, the community will do it.  Just look at how many there are for gnome-shell in the user repos https://extensions.gnome.org/.  You may miss the applets of Gnome 2, just wounder about an extension that anable to have that functionality?  What do you think what unity should have for customizability?